# Android home screen widget - how to add option to launch apps from the widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I have a nicely working widget.
I have an idea to add an option for the users to launch any (previously installed) app from the widget by pressing the dedicated button. So I want users to be able to choose 1-2 apps from their installed apps in the widget configuration part and be able to launch them from the widget.
Is there any way to add this functionality without declaring this widget a launcher?
If yes, could I get any hints, maybe some tuts, please?

I really appreciate any help you can provide.
Adam

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46513015/115145

Comment: Thanks CommonsWare, I should think about your repositories first :D